# jqGrid table styling

Tags: jqgrid

I am using the [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start) to display the data in my project. I am using [Firebug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebug) to inspect the created table. But for table columns, the width created is hardcoded. Wherein I want to give it in percentages. Is there any way wherein I can customize the element style of jqGrid?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2157011/understanding-jqgrid-column-width-behaviors)

Defining column widths in the initial table structure and setting shrinkToFit causes the widths to be treated as percentages